# android game image

Tags: android

Can you help me making a touchable image? And when you place it to its correct place, a pop up message will come and displays text. My game is a body parts game that you will be placing the body parts to its corresponding places... Help me please, I will highly appreciate your responses, thanks a lot....

```
if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {



        if (droid.isTouched()) {

            droid.setX((int)event.getX());
            droid.setY((int)event.getY());
        }
            if (roid.isTouched()) {

                roid.setX((int)event.getX());
                roid.setY((int)event.getY());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a doubt the best answer to this question is:

Buy and read this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Beginning-Android-Games-Mario-Zechner/dp/1430230428](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430230428)

It was written by the author of LibGDX which is one of the most popular android game engines. The book teaches you everything you need to know to build a complete game.